# Format DateTime field in calculated column display in browser timezone

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, timezone

I want to format my `[Start Time]` column as a *short date*.  I created a calculated column and employed the `TEXT()` method like so:

```
=TEXT([Start Time], "MM/DD/YYYY")
```

However, it appears that this is returning and formatting the *UTC* value of `[Start Time]`.  What I want is to display the formatting in the timezone that pertains to the user's experience.

*How do I ask the calculated column to take into account the user's timezone (as captured when the field was created)?*

### detailed example

If I have a DateTime field set at: `3/21/2017 12:00 AM`.

This appears to be stored, however, as: `42814.8333333333` ... which is equivalent to: `3/20/2017  8:00:00 PM UTC`.

When I apply the calculated column (above) it outputs: `3/20/2017`.  Which is not what I want.  I want `3/21/2017` ... which should be `42815`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 =TEXT( ROUNDUP([Start Time]) , "MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting - I was hoping to find an actual timezone related solution. This will work in the specific example (12:00 AM) however if the time was at 21:00 it would round to the wrong date. SharePoint is obviously managing timezones - was hoping that functionality was available to us little users.